# Cannot open c++ standard libraries when compiling x64 bits

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, compilation, 64-bit

Hei everybody! 
I have a Visual studio 2015 project. I can build in x86 meanwhile if I try to build in x64
I have the following errors. I didn't change anything about the "default" configuration.

Any clue on why I have these issues_

```
Error (active)      cannot open source file "algorithm" 
Error (active)      cannot open source file "cassert"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "cassert"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "cmath" 
Error (active)      cannot open source file "cstddef"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "cstring"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "ctype.h"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "excpt.h"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "excpt.h"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "excpt.h"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "fstream"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "functional"
Error (active)      cannot open source file "iostream"  
Error (active)      cannot open source file "limits"    
Error (active)      cannot open source file "map"   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "memory"    
Error (active)      cannot open source file "stdarg.h"  
Error (active)      cannot open source file "stdarg.h"  
Error (active)      cannot open source file "stdlib.h"
```

Comment: Do the project's include directory look the same for both targets ?

Comment: ehi @jeffrey Yes, I tried to manually force the include path, but nothing changed :/

Comment: You probably messed up by tinkering with the project settings. Start a fresh project with just #include <map>. Make sure it compiles for both targets. Copy over the nice default settings. If a fresh project, out of the box doesn't compile, ugh... reinstall VS?

Comment: ehi @Jeffrey actually $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);  was missing in the VC++ Directories/Include Directories